# Packet Sniffing Error

Tags: python, sockets, packet-sniffers

I'm running the following script:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

while True:
  print s.recvfrom(65565)
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "supersecretfilepath/error.py", line 6, in <module>
    print s.recvfrom(65565)
error: [Errno 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried lowering the buffersize, to no avail.

Comment: Your code works here (Linux), with lots and losts of output. I need to `sudo` it though, otherwise `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 3, in <module>
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 191, in __init__
    _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

Comment: I have been using administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

> `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)`

Perhaps your operating system doesn't support raw IPv4 sockets with TCP specified as the protocol.

What is it you're trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to sniff my own packets with the raw socket.